# Assert Failed ipv4-l3-protocol.cc

Tags: ns-3

When running a simulation for a channel assignment algorithm in mesh network in NS3.25 I get the following error: 
assert failed. cond="tc != 0", file=..src/internet/model/ipv4-l3-protocol.cc 
terminate called without an active exception

I have tried the simulation with different parameter settings. However, I still get the same error. I cant figure out its cause, or what should I try to eliminate it.

Answer (score 1):

Seems to me, just looking at the variable names, that you're missing Traffic Control (tc) layer in the node, since assertion fails. Have you initialized your IPv4 stack on the node using `InternetStackHelper`?

It sets a simple FIFO TC layer by default if none other is provided. If you initialized your stack manually, without using the helper, that may be the problem.